# How to copy SQL .mdf file in windows

Tags: sql-server, mdf

For my school project I need to send .mdf file to my teacher.
I'm trying to copy .mdf file of my database witch is saved in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA" folder. But windows doesn't let me do that. It gives me an error

> Open Error: Access id denied.

[image]

I tried to change folder permissions but it didn't works. I don't want backup file or script file, because my teacher said to send .mdf file.
Is there any way to copy that?

Comment: Take a backup. You don't just copy `mdf` files while the server is running, nor can you just copy them when the server has stopped. For starters, a database can use more than one data file. The data in the data file may be inconsistent if a transaction was in progress when the file was copied, requiring the transaction log file to determine which data is OK and which needs to be recovered. Finally, there may be thousands of active connections on a database. It's not possible to just stop the server just to copy the data file.

Comment: To copy database files you first need to [detach the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/detach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15). This will wait until all active connections close and pending transactions commit and take the database offline. After that you can copy the data files. The data files may contain empty or unused data pages though, unlike a backup file.

Comment: Don't detach! Just stop the database instance and you can freely access all of the associated physical files.

Comment: Although your teacher may not be in the mood to be taught themselves, it's still worthwhile to take the initiative and point out that a backup is not only the generally accepted way of transferring databases (as opposed to copying the database files) but it's also much easier to do without problems of accessing the file. If your teacher switches to requiring backups, everyone will have an easier time in the future as well. A teacher who'd complain about receiving a backup file, rather than the data file, should not be teaching.

Comment: Copying an `mdf` without the `ldf` log file is a recipe for disaster anyway

Comment: Unfortunately stop database and service dosen't works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was restricted by windows, I made a bootable flash drive with linux and run it on startup and use it to copy mdf file. It seems to be the only way which works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Option1: Stop the Database services and copy it
Option2: Detach the database

Comment: This trick dosen't work for me.